# Jquery trigger('click') not working in IOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, click

I have queue of animation and in the end of the animation i need to trigger automated click so some action will be completed. So am triggering click like this

```
jQuery('.start').trigger('click');
```

I understood that IOS have a restriction and without **Real** user **interaction** did not do anything, not triggering false click.

So is there any workaround i can do cause i cant force user to click on the button, it must be automated?

Thanks.

Comment: What about `jQuery('.start').click()` ?

Comment: I tried not working @AdamWolski

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the 'click' trigger of the button itself, instead call the action which that button is calling within its 'click' event after your animation.

Comment: The thing is that click inside another js file inside another object as a method. ANy other ways to achieve this @kiffKewitzz?

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan use some kind of mediator to trigger the function on some event

Comment: Can you give me an example please @AdamWolski

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you apply the following css to your button.

```
.start {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```